# Two indices, but only search on one index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch

Our Elasticsearch has two indices, and there is a `flag` variable in one of the indices. I want to only filter on that index without touching the other index. I was trying to use `existsQuery` to see if `flag` exists and then try to use `termQuery` to compare. However, it seems like both of my indices are getting filtered.

This is the code

```
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("discoverFlag"))
                .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("discoverFlag", true));
```

Comment: Hi, your question lacks a lot of details I am afraid. Could you please give a l large snippet of code, more information about your index.